# CodeIgniter and csv_from_result

Tags: codeigniter, csv

I have getting data from a database and using

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

echo $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);
```

however I want to change the name of my headers for the CSV for first_name is First Name...how would I go about doing that?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the columns returned by the sql query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT 
         first_name as 'First Name', last_name as 'Last Name' 
    FROM mytable
");
```

The downside is that you will have to list the columns instead of a simple `*`.