# CodeIgniter change the field names result_array();

Tags: codeigniter, csv

I am using `$data = $query->result_array();` but I would need to change my fields name from first_name to first name.

I looked up found this....

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

would I want to do something like this?

```
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
       $row = str_replace("_", " ", $row);
    }

$data = $row;
```

Comment: Why not do the replacement in your view?  Otherwise, you're going to be looping through the same data twice.

Comment: its going to a CSV file there is no view

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter and csv\_from\_result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482654/codeigniter-and-csv-from-result) - although the question is written differently, it's basically the same.

Comment: $row is an array and you are using a str_replace function on an array how it will work.......you want remove "_" from the results which you are getting am i right

Comment: A small note : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html#csv

Answer (score 0):

if you need then a new array you can easly do:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $key=> $value)
    {
       $data[] = array(
        str_replace("_", " ", $key)=>$value
       ); 
    }
```